# Location not found in Lollipop using NETWORK_PROVIDER

Tags: android, location, android-5.0-lollipop

I have tried to find the location using NETWORK_PROVIDER in android Lollipop. But it shows null. Whereas the same thing worked in lower versions.

Can anyone suggest me the solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: show your code what have you done

Comment: And make sure your device has location turned on.

Comment: @GabeSechan I don't want to turn on my location. Now is there any way to get latitude/longitude in Lollipop? For NETWORK_PROVIDER in Lollipop, is it compulsory to turn of the location?

Comment: Yes.  It must be on.  Then there's 3 modes-  device only (GPS),  high accuracy (AGPS using GPS and network/cellular), and battery saving (network only).  If you want network only, turn it on and put it in battery saving mode.  Off means you don't want any app to be able to get location.

Comment: @GabeSechan so as per your suggestion we can not get location without turning on location right?

Comment: I'm fairly certain they changed it like that, in 4.4 or 5.0.  Easy way to check is to flip the switch and see if it starts working.  Oh, you also need either cellular or wifi (preferably both) connections or it won't have data.